# Reference for Sobolev-Hölder embedding for unbounded domains

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces

I would like to know whether the following is true and references:

> If $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ is open (not necessarily bounded) and $k = n/p + r+\alpha$, and $\alpha \in (0,1),  r\in \mathbb N, k\geq 0,p\geq 1$, then there is a continuous embedding of the Sobolev space
> $$ W^{k,p}(\Omega)\to C^{r,\alpha}(\Omega)$$
> into the space of Hölder functions.

I have found in several places the case the case $k=1$, and in other places, the case when $\Omega$ is bounded. In this generality it is stated in Wikipedia for $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$. I am looking for a more reliable source.
It is possible that $\Omega$ open is not enough, in that case I would be interested to the case when $\Omega = \mathbb R^n$ or to know what are the most general hypothesis (e.g. $\Omega$ star domain).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, it suffices to prove your result for $\mathbb{R}^n$ if the
   open set $\Omega$ satifies the extension property, *i.e.* the
   existence of bounded linear operator
   $E\,:\,W^{k,p}(\Omega)\longrightarrow W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such
   that $Eu_{|_{\Omega}}=u$. It is true for sufficiently general
   $\Omega$, in particular in the case of Lipschitz domains not
   necessarily bounded, see

   > V.S. Rychkov. **On Restrictions and Extensions of the Besov and
   > Triebel–Lizorkin spaces with Respect to Lipschitz Domains**. *Journal
   > of The London Mathematical Society*, 60:237–257, 08 1999.

   Noticing that Triebel-Lizorkin and Besov spaces contains the whole
   scales of Sobolev spaces. Various other simpler extension operators
   exist, but Rychkov's is the only one that covers, in my knowlegde,
   unbounded Lipschitz domains.
2. To prove the result on  $\mathbb{R}^n$, in its full generality you
   just need the result

   $$W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\hookrightarrow
   C^{0,1-\frac{n}{p}}(\mathbb{R}^n).$$

   This is exactly the **Theorem** 9.12 of

   > H. Brezis. **Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial
   > differential equations**. *Universitext. Springer, New York*, 2011
3. To recover the general case, apply it iteratively (hence prove
   it by induction) using $\nabla u$ instead $u$, and use the fact that
   Sobolev spaces decrease as the regularity index increase and sum with the
   previous estimate.

Comment: I think one needs to be a bit careful here. Rychkov's definition of Lipschitz is more restrictive than what one would think at first.